# Restrict Woocommerce products to logged in users only

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am create an e-commerce store with the functionality to display first 5 products to all visitors and rest of the products to the logged in users only is there any hook or plugin that can help to do that?

One solution I think of is that in theme -> functions.php add a hook that triggers before all wooCoomerce loop and in there we modify the archive-products.php query like below:

```
function limited_products(){
 if(!is_logged_in()){
     global $query;
     $query->set(array('limit'=>'5')); 
 } 
}
```

I am sure there must be this sort of solution but I don't know how exactly do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize woocommerce/archive-product.php template and add a condition in the loop if count goes above 5 and user is not logged in, then continue.

But this way, if the user already has url of other products, then he/she can access it. If you want them not to access those products at all, then you will need to redirect on product details page separately when they access products other than those 5 products.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes this is what I did in the beginning but the problem with this is if they search product by the name or apply any filter they will be able to see the products that they should not see.

One solution I think of is that in theme -> `functions.php` add a hook that triggers before all wooCoomerce loop and in there we modify the `archive-products.php` query like below:

`function limited_products(){
if(!is_logged_in()){
  global $query;
  $query->set(array('limit'=>'5'));
}
}`
I am sure there must be this sort of solution but I don't know how exactly do it.